What is a "derivative security"?
I am reading the book Stochastic Calculus for Finance I The Binomial Asset Pricing Model, from Steven E. Shreve. And, at the first chapter "The Binomial No-Arbitrage Pricing Model", in page 5, it says:

In the general one-period model, we define a derivative security to be a security that pays some amount $V_1 (H)$ at time one if the coin toss results in head and pays a possibly different amount $V_1 (T)$ at time one if the coin toss results in tail.

And then, two paragraphs later, it is said:

We want to choose $X_0$ and $\Delta_0$ so that $X_1(H) = V_1(H)$ and $X_1(T) = V_1(T)$. (Note here that $V_1(H)$ and $V_1(T)$ are given quantities, the amounts the derivative security will pay off depending on the outcome of the coin tosses. At time zero, we know what the two possibilities $V_1(H)$ and $V_1(T)$ are; we do not know which of these two possibilities will be realized.)

Here,

$X_0$ refers to the value of our portfolio of stock and money market account at time one $0$;
$X_1(H)$ the value at time $1$ if event $H$ happens;
$X_1(T)$ the value at time $1$ if event $T$ happens; And
$\Delta_0$ the percentage of shares of stock bought at time zero.

My question is: Why do we want to choose $X_0$ and $\Delta_0$ so that $X_1(H) = V_1(H)$ and $X_1(T) = V_1(T)$?

I am not familiar with the textbook but what they are doing is create a portfolio composed by $\Delta_0$ shares and cash, at time zero, with the same expected value of the derivative. Then, since there is no arbitrage, the two should have the same price. Hint: try to set up a linear system.

The principle of no arbitrage states that two assets with the same payoff must have the same price. By setting up your portfolio to exactly replicate the payoffs of the derivative security in both scenarios (heads and tails), you ensure that your portfolio will have the same value as the derivative security at time 1, regardless of the outcome.

Thanks for the promptly reply. I am not sure about the meaning of "asset" in this context (sorry but I am a newbie on this), so I will take "asset" as "event" like $H$ and $T$. And as "payoff" of an event $e \in {H, T}$ at a time $t$, I will consider the formula $X_1(e) = \Delta_0 S_1(e) + (1 + r) (X_0 - \Delta_0 S_0)$, where $r$ is the interest rate. The principle of no arbitrage (paragraph 4, page 2), implies that $X_0 > 0$ or $\nexists_{\Delta_0 > 0} (X_1(H), X_1(T) \geqslant 0)$. I can not see, how the no arbitrage principle will guarantee that $X_1(H) = X_1(T)$.

In this context, an "asset" typically refers to a financial instrument, like a stock or a bond, not to an event like $H$ or $T$. The underlying asset is the stock, and the events $H$ and $T$ correspond to different potential outcomes of the stock price.

The no-arbitrage principle ensures that the price of the derivative at time 0 (which is derived from the expected payoffs) matches the constructed portfolio, eliminating any opportunity for risk-free profit.

Thanks for the clarificaton. So, semantically speaking, the $V_1(e)$ actually would be a mark of what my asset $A$ payoff must be in order to avoid opportunity cost of not investing in asset $B$, right? For insatnce, forcing $X_1(e) = V_1(e)$, i.e. the attainment of asset $A$ at time $1$ when decision $e$ ($X_1(e)$) must be the same as the attainment of asset $B$ at the same time and decision ($V_1(e)$), is a strategy to guarantee that the investment in $A$ does not produce "results" worst then those when investing in $B$, right?

Yes, that's correct.

Ok, thank you. So, one more question, why don't we simply take $X_1(e) \geqslant V_1(e)$ then? I undestrant that imposing an equality makes the proofs easier, but, regardless, $\geqslant$ would also be correct, right?

There are some cases (called super-replication) where we try to find a strategy that has higher or equal payoffs than another, but "replication" is more common and consists of finding a strategy with equal payoffs. It is a more natural and simpler problem, with more applications.

Thank you so much.
